# How to Edit WordPress plugin css file?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in technology field. So, My question may look funny. But, I have wasted a lot of time. So, finally I decided to take help from you guys.

Let me give you some important points that i have done, so that you can understand it what i want to ask.

I want to create a website using WordPress and Bluehost for hosting. So,
I went to Bluehost website, Bought a domain and installed WordPress from there. Then, I went to http://my-website-name.com/wp-admin/, logged in there. I chose my desired theme and some plugin.

Now, I want to edit css file of a plugin(Name is syntaxhighlighter). But, I am not able to find the css file. Can you guys help me to find it? If you have any tutorial link please send me.

Also, my website is not live. As many tutorials suggested, I checked in cPanel of Bluehost account, But, I didn't find anything there.

Am I missing some steps in order to create a website?
Some tutorials were using localhost to edit plugin css. As I am newbie in this field, I couldn't get how to use localhost to edit css file?
If you have any idea, please share with me.

Comment: This would be a good place to start reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin | https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1):

It is usually best to add styles to your theme or child theme CSS to overwrite plugin styles (if that plugin doesn't give the ability to customize appearance). The reason for this is because when the plugin is updated then any changes to the plugin's CSS will be overwritten.

If you cannot edit your theme's CSS file, you can use a plugin like this one to add CSS to your WordPress site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/.

Comment: you mean i should goto Appearance -> editor -> style.css. Then, add plugin style to this file?

Comment: Generally yes, but be mindful that if you are using a downloaded theme that updates to that theme may wipe out any changes that you make to that file. Use a child theme unless you are building the theme yourself.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help @mbacon40 .. will give it a try.. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can edit WordPress plugin css file by locating the css file on your server through various means.

For syntaxhighlighter:

The css file for syntaxhighlighter can be found under lets say plugin - > syntax_highlighter -> Inc -> css folder. but in some cases css files can be found in other files i.e assets UI instead of the usual Inc folder.

Here is what you have to do to edit your CSS file.
-locate wordpress plugin folder here, wp-content/plugins
-locate the plugin you want to edit, syntax_highlighter
-locate the CSS file (in your case in Inc folder) and edit.

OR

Here's is the best thing to do.
- login to Admin panel -> Appearance -> Editor and overwrite the plugin styles in your child theme.